# If statement layout not right

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to create a program to assign cards a value and then depending which player gets the highest card then they win a point now the area which i cant get to work is the last if statement as it does it after every round not the 7 as needed.

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Card {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int player1= 0;
        int player2 = 0;
        int i = 1;

        while ( i <= 7) {
            int player1Card = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;
            int player2Card = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;

            System.out.println("player 1 = " + player1Card);
            System.out.println("player 2 = " + player2Card);

           if (player1Card > player2Card) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins!!!");
                player1 = player1 + 1;
            } else if (player1Card == player2Card){
                System.out.println("It's a bore draw");
                player1 = player1 + 0;
                player2= player2 + 0;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins!!!!!");
                player2 = player2 + 1;
            }
            System.out.println("Player 1 points " + player1);
            System.out.println("Player 2 points " + player2);
            i++;

            if (player1 > player2) {
                System.out.println("The winner is player 1 with " + player1 + " points");
            } else if (player1 == player2) {
                System.out.println("Its a draw");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The winner is Player 2 with " + player2 + " points");
            }     
      }
```

Comment: What is it that you expect will cause the `if` statement to be only executed on the last round?

Comment: that the 7 rounds have been done

Comment: Sure, but *how* does the program know that this is your intent?  It will reach that block of code (and so execute it) every time it's going round the `while` loop.  You need to think of some way to stop the program flow from reaching those conditions until every round has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement needs to come after the end of the while loop. Move the last `}` to be before the if statement you want to be executed after all 7 times have run.

Comment: Also try Ctrl-Shift-F to autoformat your source so you can better see which { matches which }

Comment: Depending on your IDE. I use Ctrl+Alt+L in IntelliJ, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting that Eclipse is not the whole world all the time.

Comment: thank you guys had been staring at it for ages that was the problem i think :)